# Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined while trying to create a Worker within another Worker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Spawning_subworkers) says:

> Workers may spawn more workers if they wish. So-called sub-workers
>   must be hosted within the same origin as the parent page. Also, the
>   URIs for subworkers are resolved relative to the parent worker's
>   location rather than that of the owning page. This makes it easier for
>   workers to keep track of where their dependencies are.

But when I try to create a `Worker` in another `Worker`:

```
var worker = new Worker('foo.js');
```

I get an exception in Chrome.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

IE works though (surprisingly). Is this documented somewhere? Is there a proper cross browser way to spawn a `Worker` from another `Worker`? Doing web search I don't see many (or rather any) code samples of spawning subworkers.

EDIT: Adding some more links:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#delegation
https://whatwg.org/demos/workers/multicore/page.html (does not work in Chrome)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct. This is a bug. You can find the [reported bug here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666) and a polyfill is [available here](https://github.com/dmihal/Subworkers).